# Android : Downloading files from FTP Server using SimpleFtp?

Tags: android, ftp, download

I've upload some files to my ftp server using [simpleftp](http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/) method. Now, i'm in need to download these files from my server using Simpleftp. Is this possible to download it using simpleftp. anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, simpleftp is only made for uploading